# javascript code to check special characters and add double slash before that?

Tags: javascript, regex, special-characters

My string contains some of the special characters that needs to be escaped with (\) double backslash before the string. My piece of code below:

```
var data = "abckdef)ghijkl)-8-mno-3-(pqrstuvw-1-xyz)-5-thiaa-1-aza-";
var iChars = "!@#$%^&*()+=-[]\\\';,./{}|\":<>?~_";
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (iChars.indexOf(data.charAt(i)) != -1) {
        console.log("Your string has special characters. \nThese are not allowed.");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Expected Result would be:

```
abckdef\)ghijkl\)\-8\-mno\-3\-\(pqrstuvw\-1\-xyz\)\-5\-thiaa\-1\-aza\-
```

Above code finds the special characters in my string, but I wanted to add (\\) before every occurrences of the special characters. Any help on this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use a regex replacement:

Match:

```
/[!@#$%^&*()+=\-[\]\\';,./{}|":<>?~_]/
```

Replace to:

```
\$&
```

```
>>> data.replace(/[!@#$%^&*()+=\-[\]\\';,./{}|":<>?~_]/g, "\\$&")
... "abckdef\)ghijkl\)\-8\-mno\-3\-\(pqrstuvw\-1\-xyz\)\-5\-thiaa\-1\-aza\-"
```

Comment: If you don't **show** the `replace` call, you just know people will use `"\$&"` as the replacement string...

Comment: @AvinashRaj Good idea, that's a really neat trick especially for regex golf.

Comment: what if i want three slashes instead of 1

Answer (score 2):

Regex:

```
([!@#$%^&*()+=\[\]\\';,./{}|":<>?~_-])
```

Replacement string:

```
\$1
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/zW8zX6/1)

```
> var data = "abckdef)ghijkl)-8-mno-3-(pqrstuvw-1-xyz)-5-thiaa-1-aza-";
undefined
> var result = data.replace(/([!@#$%^&*()+=\[\]\\';,./{}|":<>?~_-])/g, "\\$1");
undefined
> console.log(result);
abckdef\)ghijkl\)\-8\-mno\-3\-\(pqrstuvw\-1\-xyz\)\-5\-thiaa\-1\-aza\-
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this plug and play function.

```
var data = "abckdef)ghijkl)-8-mno-3-(pqrstuvw-1-xyz)-5-thiaa-1-aza-";

function escapeSpecialCaseChar(text) {
   return text.replace(/[-[\]{}()*+?.,\\^$|#\s]/g, '\\$&');
}
```

console.log(escapeSpecialCaseChar(data));

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to escape anything other than alphanumeric character then make it simple

Find what :`([^a-zA-Z0-9])`
Replacement: `\\$1`

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/uB9oN1/1)

Sample code:

```
var re = /([^a-zA-Z0-9])/g; 
var str = 'abckdef)ghijkl)-8-mno-3-(pqrstuvw-1-xyz)-5-thiaa-1-aza-';
var subst = '\\$1'; 

var result = str.replace(re, subst);
```

output: (same as expected)

```
abckdef\)ghijkl\)\-8\-mno\-3\-\(pqrstuvw\-1\-xyz\)\-5\-thiaa\-1\-aza\-
```

Comment: @user3218114 I've had to file a bug on the regex101 project issue tracker as they've never escaped character literals properly.