# Add double slash before characters in both java and javascript

Tags: java, javascript, regex, escaping, special-characters

I want to add double slash `\\` to all these characters in a String in both java and javascript.

```
!"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[\]^`{|}~
```

For example `Test!test` will be `Test\\!test` and
                              `Test\test` will be `Test\\\test`.
Do I have to replace each of them in a separate statement or there is a way to write this in one statement. Thank you.

Comment: did you try regular expressions?

Comment: My answer is below :-) ............................................................................................................................ The real question should be why you need to do this...

Answer (score 0):

You can use lookahead to match the position before specified characters and replace that position:

```
(?=[!"#$%&'()*+,.\/:;<=>?@[\]\\^`{|}~])
```

And replace with `\\`

Comment: Here is a javascript solution but this does not seems to work for `\\` itself [javascript code to check special characters and add double slash before that?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25376698/javascript-code-to-check-special-characters-and-add-double-slash-before-that)

Answer (score 0):

Java:

```
String oldString = "!\"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[\\]^`{|}~";
String newString = "";
for (int i = 0; i < oldString.length(); i++)
{
    newString += "//" + oldString.charAt(i);
}
```

JavaScript:

```
var oldString = "!\"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[\\]^`{|}~";
var newString = "";

for (var i = 0; i < oldString.length; i++)
{
    newString += "//" + oldString.charAt(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@DUUUDE123 Some data we get back from web service has only one unique value we can use to identify the object... and it could contain special characters, we used this String on the page html tags, but when it has special characters, jquery selector does not work unless we escape these special characters add "//" before them. But this is actually a very stupid idea... now I used java String default hashCode method to hash this String, and I got a js method with the same simple algorithm. Although hashCode is not guaranteed to be unique, but in this case it should be good enough. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a way to write it in one statement in both languages using regex. It's a little confusing because you have to escape some specials characters.

In Java:

```
String test = "A!B\"C#D$E%F&G'H(I)J*K+L,M.N/O:P;Q<R=S>U?U@V[W\\\\X]Y^Z`A{B|C}D~";
String escaped = test.replaceAll("([!\"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@\\[\\]^`{|}~])", "\\\\\\\\$1");
System.out.println(escaped);
//Prints: A\\!B\\"C\\#D\\$E\\%F\\&G\\'H\\(I\\)J\\*K\\+L\\,M\\.N\\/O\\:P\\;Q\\<R\\=S\\>U\\?U\\@V\\[W\\X\\]Y\\^Z\\`A\\{B\\|C\\}D\\~
```

In Javascript:

```
var test = "A!B\"C#D$E%F&G'H(I)J*K+L,M.N/O:P;Q<R=S>U?U@V[W\\\\X]Y^Z`A{B|C}D~"
var escaped = test.replace(/([!"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[\]^`{|}~])/g,'\\\\$1')
alert (escaped)
//Shows: A\\!B\\"C\\#D\\$E\\%F\\&G\\'H\\(I\\)J\\*K\\+L\\,M\\.N\\/O\\:P\\;Q\\<R\\=S\\>U\\?U\\@V\\[W\\X\\]Y\\^Z\\`A\\{B\\|C\\}D\\~
```